# How can I get the profile graph on ArcMap to display specific points?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, dem, profile

I currently have 2 layers:

1) DEM of existing terrain
2) Polygon in vector format of future water retention basin

I need to draw cross sections across this basin for eventual cut and fill calcs. I already know how to create a profile of the existing terrain based on my DEM. However I don't know how I can have the profile curve display the extents (or at least start and end points) of the basin on the graph. IS there any way to incorporate vector data into a profile drawn of a DEM? Or to have the profile curve display the specific points that are the  start and end points of the basin?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you are trying to know, on your DEM profile graph, where the water retention basin starts and ends. Here's a bit of a hacked-together idea:

What if you raserized your water retention basin polygon? Then, using the same "cut" that you generated your profile from the DEM, generate a profile for the rasterized basin by switching the layer on the 3D Analyst toolbar ( I assume that is what you are using, [as shown in this nifty Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELmXNrEwKZk)).

That way, you essentially have two profile graphs, one from the DEM and one from the rasterized basin, except that "profile graph" from the rasterized basin would pretty much be a straight line--but the axes will be the same on both profile graphs. Export both profile graphs and overlay them.

You may be able to figure out your basin extents with Excel by playing with the overlaid graphs.